# How can I construct this file tree based on what files the user is allowed to view?

Tags: php, permissions, tree, directory

I have an array of files that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [path] => RootFolder
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => RootFolder\error.log
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [path] => RootFolder\test
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => RootFolder\test\asd.txt
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => folder
            [path] => RootFolder\test\sd
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => file
            [path] => RootFolder\test\sd\testing.txt
        )
)
```

I parse this array and create a tree like view based on the depth of the files ('/' count). It looks like this:

```
RootFolder
    - error.log
    - test
        - asd.txt
        - sd
            - testing.txt
```

What I have now is an array of filepaths the user is allowed to view. I need to take this array into account when constructing the above tree. That array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filePath] => RootFolder\test\sd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filePath] => RootFolder\error.log
        )

)
```

It would be easy to do a `if in_array($path, $allowed)` but that won't give me the tree. Just a list of files...

Another part I'm stumped on is this requirement: If the user has access to view the folder `test`, they then have access to all children of that folder.

My idea was to simply parse the filepaths. For example, I'd confirm that `RootFolder\test\sd` was a directory and then create a tree based on the '/' count. Like I was doing earlier. Then, since this is a directory, I'd pull out all files within this directory and show them to the user. However, I'm having trouble converting this to working code...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tree = array();
// keep one:
$permNeeded = '?'; //something you're searching for exactly
$permNeeded = array('?', '?'); // multiple allowed perms
// be carefull with octal data checking permisions!

function checkPerms($permFileHas){
    // keep one:
    return $permFileHas==$permNeeded;
    return in_array($permFileHas, $permNeeded);
}

function parseDir($dir){
    $contents = scandir($dir);
    foreach($contents as $file){
        if(in_array($file, array('.', '..')){
            continue; // skip . and ..
        }
        if(is_dir($file)){
            parseDir($file);
            continue;
        }
        if(checkPerms(fileperms($file)){
            $tree[] = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
        }
    }
}

parseDir('/the/dir/user/have/perms');
```

That should do the trick :)